# Find a Basis for the Vectors $W=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\} \subseteq\mathbb{F}_{2} ^{5}$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I've to find the basis of $W=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\} \subseteq\mathbb{F}_{2} ^{5}$

$v_{1}=(1,0,1,0,1)$ , $v_{2}=(0,0,1,0,1)$ , $v_{3}=(0,0,0,1,0)$ , $v_{4}=(1,0,1,1,1)$ , $v_{5}=(1,0,0,1,0)$

$\mathbb{F}_{2}$ is a Field with $2$ Elements

so now first I've wrote a linear combination for the span:

$a \cdot1$ + $b \cdot0$ + $c \cdot0$ + $d \cdot1$ + $e \cdot1$

$a \cdot0$ + $b \cdot0$ + $c \cdot0$ + $d \cdot0$ + $e \cdot0$

$a \cdot1$ + $b \cdot1$ + $c \cdot0$ + $d \cdot1$ + $e \cdot0$

$a \cdot0$ + $b \cdot0$ + $c \cdot1$ + $d \cdot1$ + $e \cdot1$

$a \cdot1$ + $b \cdot1$ + $c \cdot0$ + $d \cdot1$ + $e \cdot0$

so i got:

$a+d+e=w_{1}$

$0=w_{2}$

$a+b+d=w_{3}$

$c+d+e=w_{4}$

$a+b+d=w_{5}$

am i now on the right Way? or completly wrong? Am i right that i have to show the Basis with the linear combination?

Comment: write them as columns of a matrix and bring it to reduce row echelon form. then the columns with pivots make a basis.

Comment: or since it's 5 vectors in a 5 dimensional space, put them in columns of a matrix and take determinant. if the determinant is nonzero, then they are independent, and are already a basis.

Comment: so ive to write the Vectors as a Matrix or the combinations? Is that way that i have wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\\1&0&1&1&1\\1&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Its rows are the vectors that you provided. If the determinant was non null, that would be great, but, alas, it is $0$. So, add the first row to the fourth and the fifth rows, thereby getting:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, you add the second row to the fifth one, and you get:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, you can stop, since the third, and fourth and the fifth rows are all equal. Thereby, a basis of your space is$$\bigl\{(1,0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,0,1),(0,0,0,1,0)\bigr\}.$$